# update table column with select from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know this question has been asked but I cannot manage to get the results I want following answers to similar question.
I have 2 tables
Table1:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (session_id INT, timestamp INT, track DOUBLE PRECISION);

INSERT INTO table1 (session_id) VALUES (106502),(137226),
  (114701),(124942),(155663)
```

Table2:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table2 (session_id INT, seconds INT, lat DOUBLE PRECISION,
  lon DOUBLE PRECISION, track DOUBLE PRECISION);

INSERT INTO table2 (session_id, seconds, lat, lon, track)
VALUES ( 106502, 1462559236, 41.1726876, -8.5985753,150),
     (106502, 1462559237, 41.1726365, -8.5985595, 155),
     (106502, 1462559238, 41.1725735, -8.5985308,156),
     (106502, 1462559239, 41.1725079, -8.5984963, 156),
     (106502, 1462559240, 41.1724459, -8.5984539, 154),
     (137226, 1513974852, 41.1078345, -8.6268529, 194),
     (137226, 1513974853, 41.1077562,-8.6268664, 184),
     (137226, 1513974854, 41.1076747,-8.6268582, 173),
     (114701, 1467878080, 41.1654988, -8.6027799, 69),
     (114701, 1467878081, 41.1655208, -8.6027348, 49)
```

The 2 other columns of `table1` are empty, and I want update it from `table2`.

So I issued:

```sql
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET timestamp = t2.seconds, 
       track = t2.track
from table2 t2
where t1.session_id = t2.session_id

session_id | timestamp | track
-----------+-----------+------
124942     |           |
155663     |           |
106502     |1462559236 | 150
114701     |1467878081 | 49
137226     |1513974854 | 173
```

**Required results:**

```sql
session_id | timestamp | track
-----------+-----------+------
124942     |           |
155663     |           |
106502     |1462559236 | 150
106502     |1462559237 | 155
106502     |1462559238 | 156
106502     |1462559239 | 156
106502     |1462559240 | 154
137226     |1513974852 | 194
137226     |1513974853 | 184
137226     |1513974854 | 173
114701     |1467878080 |  69
114701     |1467878081 |  49
```

This is illustrated in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W7taMd9V).

Comment: @ariwan I think you need to be carfull with the first update. Since `session_id` is not unique in `table2`, the record selected for the update will not be deterministic: "When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable." https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to overwrite blank rows in `table1` with their `table2` counterparts matched by `session_id`, adding the rest and leaving the unmatched blanks in place.

```sql
delete from table1 
where session_id in (select session_id from table2);

insert into table1
      (session_id, timestamp, track) 
select session_id, seconds,   track 
from table2;
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rl8uKA7a)

Comment: Is this not going to include sessions from `table2` that are not needed in `table1` please?

Comment: Which ones are not needed? For now it seems this produces what you specified as required results.